# Java wrapped generics compilation error

Tags: java

I have a very basic code to reproduce the issue:

```
public class Main {
  public static <T extends Number> void bar(Wrapper<List<T>> wrapper) {
    // do something
  }

  public static void foo(Wrapper<List<? extends Number>> wrapper) {
    // do something
  }

  public static <T extends Number> void bar2(List<T> aList) {
    // do something
  }

  public static void foo2(List<? extends Number> aList) {
    // do something
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> aList = Collections.singletonList(1);
    foo2(aList); // compiles
    bar2(aList); // compiles

    Wrapper<List<Integer>> wrapper = new Wrapper<>(Collections.singletonList(1));
    foo(wrapper); // not compiles
    bar(wrapper); // compiles
  }

  private static class Wrapper<T> {
    private final T t;

    public Wrapper(T t) {
      this.t = t;
    }
  }
}
```

So the question is why javac gives an error when I try to compile the code:

```
Main.java:26: error: method foo in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
    foo(wrapper); // not compiles
    ^
  required: Wrapper<List<? extends Number>>
  found: Wrapper<List<Integer>>
  reason: argument mismatch; Wrapper<List<Integer>> cannot be converted to Wrapper<List<? extends Number>>
1 error
```

Comment: It doesn't like the wildcard definition.  declare it the same way as `bar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: The explanation from the linked question partly answers on my question, however I believe that the questions are slightly different and it would be usefull to keep this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wrapper<List<Integer>>` is not a subtype of `Wrapper<List<? extends Number>>`.

Use `Wrapper<? extends List<? extends Number>>`.

---

To see why you can't pass `Wrapper<List<Integer>>` to `foo`, consider the following: I've replaced `Wrapper` with `List`, but it's the same thing from a type safety point of view.

```
List<List<? extends Number>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Integer>> intList = new ArrayList<>();
```

So, you can add something to `list`:

```
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0.0));
list.add(doubles);
```

But, if you were able to write this assignment:

```
list = intList;
```

Then calling `list.add(doubles)` would mean there would then be a `List<Double>` in `intList`. This is not type safe, and thus forbidden.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/nZIXL2)

However, if `list` has type `List<? extend List<? extends Number>>`, then you can't invoke `add` on it, so you can't get into this situation, so that would be safe.

Comment: the same result :)

Comment: public static void foo(Wrapper<? extends List<? extends Number>> wrapper) and the method invocation Wrapper<List<Integer>> wrapper = new Wrapper<>(Collections.singletonList(1)); foo(wrapper);

Comment: [Yes, that works](http://ideone.com/Iy8gNW). Try clicking on the links I'm posting, they show it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because Java generics are not covariant.

In your case

```
Wrapper<List<Integer>>
```

instance cannot be used as

```
Wrapper<List<? extends Number>>
```

parameter because

```
List<Integer>
```

does not extend

```
List<? extends Number>
```

Comment: Because  "bar" receives "Wrapper<List<T>>" where T will be Integer which extends Number.

Comment: So the type of T is being resolved prior to type of Wrapper's list type, whereas the original foo case the type of Wrapper's list is not being resolved at all, right?

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<Integer>` is not a subclass of `List<? extends Number>`